# Creating a sideloading exe for UWP WinRT code

Tags: uwp

Can anyone give me the steps or web page that lists the steps on how to create a stand alone EXE for running on any PC. This is not an app that will be published to the Microsoft Store. I know a page exists because I have done this before some time ago, but have lost the link.

I am NOT trying to create a full-fledge package. I have some working code that I want to run on another computer and you can't just create an exe on the development computer and have it run on another computer using UWP WinRT C++ code in VS2019, it won't run.

This is my recollection of the process I performed around Sept of 2021 from a Microsoft MSDN page which listed the steps. I no longer remember how it was done or where or how to find the page. My thought is there are about 3 steps you must perform, and I know one of them is to sign the app with a certificate. The other thing is, I don't think it is a sideloaded app because I did perform all the steps back in Sept and my development computer is not set for sideloaded apps. I checked my browser history and it only goes back 3 months, so no luck there.

All I am trying to do is check my code using another computer and because UWP apps are special, I need to create the executable a certain way. That certain way is what I can't find and I know it exists. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you means Installing Windows 10 apps from a [web page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/app-installer/installing-windows10-apps-web#signing-the-app-package). I have to say, there is no such tool could package uwp as exe file. it is only packaged as msix or appx file.

Comment: the app file is created as ".msixbundle" when you publish your code. No ".exe" files is created.. You can use third party app and create the .exe file using all package files which is created after publish..